# What is Fluid inline form of <wwt:getCategory uid="{record.uid}" as="records">{records.title}</wwt:getCategory>?

Tags: typo3, fluid

How can i get the inline form of this fluid tag ?

```
<wwt:getCategory uid="{record.uid}" as="records">{records.title}</wwt:getCategory>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
{records.title ->wwt:getCategory(uid: record.uid, as: 'records')}
```

It should be the same inline syntax like ForViewHelper.